# Как сделать так, чтобы текст вводился туда, где стоит курсор?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я делаю голосовой помощник, и одной из его функций будет голосовой ввод текста. Скажем, открыл блокнот и ввожу текст голосом.

```py
def recognizer():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.7)
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        recognizetext = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
    except:
        recognizetext = recognizer()
    return recognizetext
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вводился `recognizetext`, туда, где стоит курсор?

P.S Записывать текст прямиком в файл не вариант

Comment: а сейчас куда вводится?

Comment: Пока никуда, не могу найти стандартного решения

Comment: В смысле, тебе нужно, чтоб твое приложение работало в фоне, а распознанную речь выводило в любое приложение так, как-будто оно набирается с клавиатуры?

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov Абсолютно верно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Модуль по работе с клавиатурой для Python](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard)

Следующий код не проверен, но, по логике, должно работать:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.write(recognizer())
```

Comment: А "встроенного" решения нет?)

Comment: Посмотри в код модуля: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/tree/master/keyboard в глаза сразу бросается проблематика (под разные ОС, разная реализация). Посмотри как там реализована работа с клавиатурой и реши, стоит это переписывать самостоятельно, или нет. Встроенных аналогичных модулей, на сколько мне известно - нет.